What are the differences between a Web Server and a Web Server Gateway Interface (WSGI)?
I get confused between WSGI and a web server. I'd like an explanation of the differences between them, or if they are the same thing. And thank you in advance.

A web server is a program that binds to a port and processes incoming HTTP(S) requests (and possibly other protocols).
WSGI is an implementation detail of how specifically Python applications can be integrated into such a web server, such that the web server can delegate processing of requests to Python.
